# wait a little before finish my activity

Tags: android

What's the best way to wait before my activity is finished?

In fact I launch a new activity named MasterNumber from MainActivity with "startActivityForResult". MasterNumber send a SMS and shows a Toast to say "SMS Sent",  but MasterNumber activity is closed so quickly that the Toast is showed in MainActivity.

Here is the content of MainActivity:

```
//Lorsqu'on clique sur le bouton "Send"
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.masterbutton1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(automatikRN, null, "#00#", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
    }
});
```

and here is the content of MasterNumber (activity)

```
//Lorsqu'on clique sur le bouton Add Master Number
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainbutton2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //On va appeler l'activité MasterNumber (#RECIPIENTNUMBERAUTOMATIK-1)
        Intent setMasterNumber = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MasterNumber.class);
        setMasterNumber.putExtra("MN", recipientNumber);    //on lui fournit le n° du dest. afin qu'il soit saisit automatiquement
        startActivityForResult(setMasterNumber, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: All the required code put inside the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask and put the finish() in onpostexecute method when you getting not null

Comment: @sunil Do you have any example please? Or can you do it quickly for me? Because I'm new in android & i don't know what you talking about..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
//Lorsqu'on clique sur le bouton "Send"
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.masterbutton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(automatikRN, null, "#00#", null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
        }, Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
            }
        });
```

By using a postDelayed runnable, all actions places inside the run() method will be executed after the Toast.LENGTH_LONG time has passed.

Comment: Thank you my friend but i don't see any difference.. Maybe can I add more time to wait?

Comment: Using Toast.LENGTH_LONG does not work because, if you actually look at the Toast class, LENGTH_LONG = 1, so it will only wait 1ms.